# Http request to webhdfs but gives FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, http, hadoop, hdfs

I installed hadoop 1.0.4. I enabled the webhdfs and use the curl command to get a Home Directory.

```
curl -i "http://172.16.30.40:50075/webhdfs/v1?user.name=ubantu&op=GETFILESTATUS"
```

its working for  GETHOMEDIRECTORY but not working for other operations like GETFILESTATUS, LISTSTATUS etc

I get the exception

```
**{"RemoteException":{"exception":"FileNotFoundException","javaClassName":"java.io.FileNotFoundException","message":"File /webhdfs/v1 not found."}}**
```

Here is the conf files:

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
     <property>
         <name>dfs.replication</name>
         <value>3</value>
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
     </property>
     <property>
       <name>dfs.support.append</name>
       <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone give some suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#GETHOMEDIRECTORY), to access the home directory you should use `curl -i "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/?op=GETHOMEDIRECTORY"`

Also, try using :50070. That is the port I use for webdfs and it works fine.

```
curl -i "http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/?op=GETHOMEDIRECTORY"
```

**Update:**

In your example you are not specifying a path of a file to check the status of.
In the example below if you swap /path/to/your/ with the path to the file then change 'file' with your file name then what does that give you?

```
curl -i  "http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/path/to/your/file?op=GETFILESTATUS"
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same its working for GETHOMEDIRECTORY but not working for other operations like GETFILESTATUS,LISTSTATUS etc.

Comment: yes Its done by adding user dir, http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/user?op=GETFILESTATUS

Comment: How can I do other operations like OPEN, WRITE and READ with HDFS using webhdfs?

Comment: Those steps are a bit trickier than some of the basic ones. You need to issue two commands. The first command you request to write the file and webdfs then replies with the host and port to send the request to. Then you make a follow up command to write your file to the location just provided. (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#CREATE)